# Fade layers in from edge of the screen (but not the whole image)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I have three layers:

1) fade foreground (currently a black and white gradient)
2) foreground (contains roads, buildings, vehicles etc)
3) background gradient

What I am trying to is fade in the foreground layers from the edge of the screen from 0% transparency (black in the gradient), to the white part of the gradient (100% transparency).

The layers in the foreground span across multiple artboards, so ideally I'd like to do this without having to flatten the layers so I can just have this part of the image transparent.

I know how to achieve this in Photoshop but am unsure in Illustrator. Any assistance would be gratefully received.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Opacity Mask

- If working in CMYK mode.... make certain the "black" in the gradient is actually the **`Registration`** black (yes, Registration)
- If working RGB ensure the black is R0G0B0 and not simply K100%.

The above colors are *required* for masking to work properly and actually hide 100% of all the colors. If you find your mask is not hiding everything as you expect, it may be because the "black" in the mask is not full color.

---

- Ensure the gradient object is on top in the stacking order. It will be used as a mask.
- Select the gradient rectangle and everything you want to fade.
- On the **Transparency Panel** (Window > Transparency) click `Make Mask` button.

[image]

You'll see this new **Opacity mask** take effect on the artwork. From here, you *may* need to adjust the `clip` or `invert` options depending upon the artwork construction.

[image]

Working with **Opacity Masks** in AI is similar to working with Layer Masks in Photoshop. If you want to edit the Mask, you need to click the mask thumbnail on the **Transparency Panel**. Conversely, if you wish to edit the artwork, you need to click the artwork thumbnail on the **Transparency Panel**.

These are the basics of creating an **Opacity Mask**. Opacity masks can be created from vector OR raster content in Illustrator. Unlike *Clipping Masks*, Opacity Masks are helpful when you desire a mask which contains soft transitions in transparency. However, they will also work with hard edge objects if needed.

<sub>(CC2017 Transparency panel screen shot, but functionality is the same in newer versions)</sub>

Comment: [Perfect](https://imgur.com/a/wMPlw1P). Thanks so much!